# TabBar Image Insets Not Transferring To AdHoc Build

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uiedgeinsets

So, the below code is centering all of my tab bar images, and it works correctly when built by hitting run, but when I load an AdHoc build, only the last image is centered correctly.

```
[[[self tabBar].items objectAtIndex:0] setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2.0, 0, -2.0, 0)];
[[[self tabBar].items objectAtIndex:1] setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2.0, 0, -2.0, 0)];
[[[self tabBar].items objectAtIndex:2] setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2.0, 0, -2.0, 0)];
[[[self tabBar].items objectAtIndex:3] setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1.0, 0, -1.0, 0)];
[[[self tabBar].items objectAtIndex:4] setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4.5, 0, -4.5, 0)];
```

Any idea why this may be occurring?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few cleans and moving some code around so the values change right before the view loads, they are positioned correctly on both builds!